# Docker container only runs dashboard app on localhost:4200 and when localhost:8080 it display the nginx webpage

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, containers, localhost

So I wrote this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install -g ionic

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=build /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

When it run the command `npm run build` it is going to create the `Dist` folder
the second last line is going to remove the things from the folder `nginx/html` and than the last line is going to replace this folder with the files from the `Dist` folder, where is the `Index.html`.

when i run the code:
`docker build -t dashboard-app:v1 .` it creates the image

Than i run the code: `docker run --name dashboard-app-container -d -p 8080:80 dashboard-app:v1`

when i go to `localhost:8080` it show " NGINX. If you see this page, the nginx web server is succesfully installed and working. Further coonfig. is required"

I dont know if my problem is that docker is not being able to replace the Dist folder and finding the index html or if is some port problem.

When i run it on `localhost:4200` i can see the dashboard app.

Any sugestion???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly hard to know what is your `Dist` folder containing and what was copied over to the `nginx/html/` location.

As long as you get a response on port `8080`, it means that nginx is running but is not able to find `index.html` page in the `nginx/html/` folder.

What I suggest doing is to run your Docker image with the following command from a terminal. Notice, the `-d` is removed, you will be able to see the logs from the container:

```
docker run --name dashboard-app-container -p 8080:80 dashboard-app:v1
```

In another terminal connect to the image using the following command:

```
docker exec -it dashboard-app:v1 sh
```

This will open a shell to the container. You will have to navigate to `/usr/share/nginx/html` location and investigate its content. You will be able to see what was copied over from the `Dist` folder and adjust the Dockerfile aftewards.

Comment: Hello. when i am doing this i getting this: /usr/share/nginx/html # dir 
sh: dir: not found . I bielive that is empty so it is not working moving the files from the Dist folder. I am trying to figure out how to write the docker file. any idea? thank you!!